# Teradata Partition By to SnowFlake Cluster By

Tags: teradata, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In Teradata we specify partition by on huge tables to make data retrieval faster and effective.
In Snowflake though it does Micro Partitioning itsely, we still can specify CLUSTER BY right?

Does Cluster By support Multi Level Partitioning?

How will below look in Snowflake?

PARTITION BY ( RANGE_N(trans_dt  BETWEEN DATE '2012-12-01' AND DATE '2025-12-31' EACH INTERVAL '1' MONTH ), CASE_N(rec_ind='Y',
rec_ind='N',
rec_ind not in('Y','n')));

Comment: I would not equate Teradata partitioning to Snowflake clustering directly and I would be careful with multiple cluster keys unless the table is extremely large. However, without the details of how large your table is, how it is queried, etc. it is difficult to make a direct suggestion.  It is possible that you may want to cluster by the same fields you are partitioning on, but it isn't always true.

Comment: Does Snowflake allow to remove or add cluster key without the need of moving data to the new table structure with Cluster Key Added. In Teradata, to remove/add partition, we have to create a backup table and then move the data.

Comment: And what about format of Cluster By command

Comment: In general the CLUSTER KEY controls how re-clustering (aka auto-clustering) re-sorts data. But does not in of itself force any shape on the data. If you insert in in a form/pattern that does not align with your CLUSTER then you have unaligned data. For which you will pay huge auto clustering costs to reorder your data. The first rule is insert your data in the way you want to read it.

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava if you remove a cluster key...you don't need to do anything.  If you add or modify a cluster key, then I recommend leveraging an `INSERT OVERWRITE` statement with an `ORDER BY` clause before modify the cluster key to save some costs.  As a note, clustering a table in Snowflake does NOT sort the data.  It groups and consolidates data based on the cluster columns, which isn't really sorting it.